# Where did my answer go?

Tags: support, specific-answer, markdown-preview

I just answered my own question, [Calculate the probability of n of the same event happening first](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1105388/calculate-the-probability-of-n-of-the-same-event-happening-first), then edited the question to clarify it and my answer disappeared!

Comment: I see no evidence of an answer, deleted or otherwise.

Comment: Nor do I. That's the problem! I spent a fair bit of time writing the answer.

Comment: There are some cases I know that I've lost answers by leaving the page in what I guess must have been an unexpected way. The script on the page does not catch my leaving and does not warn me that I have edits pending.

Comment: Have you tried opening the page from your browser history. If you're lucky, you might get some of your edits back.

Comment: It's a bit annoying because I had a complex MathJax formula and if it didn't save properly I should have a partially completed answer that I can continue.

Comment: Yes, I tried going back. My browser is good like that and remembers the contents of unsubmitted forms, but no, nothing.

Comment: Drafts of answers are also stored server-side, though only for one answer. (So, if you start writing another post, the earlier draft is lost.)

Comment: @Fundamental I'm guessing then that my answer wasn't saved properly and that by editing my question the draft got erased.

Comment: @Fundamental: I believe that the browser remembers the form contents, but backs them up periodically to an SE server. I figured the SE server copy would be gone, but hoped that the browser's memory might have been retained. No such luck, this time.

Comment: @CJDennis: I can't think of anything else. I'm sorry for your loss.

Comment: [Post drafts are stored for 7 days](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/111578/259867)

Comment: Oh, well, it was a partial answer anyway. It was very good but only for a limited case. It gives me the chance to work out the rest of the answer before I _attempt_ to post it again.

Comment: Personally I tend to write longer answers in an editor on my disk. (I am familiar enough with both MarkDown and MathJax syntax so that I don't really need to view the post rendered and if I do, I either run LaTeX - if there is not much MarkDown - or copy the answer in progress to the editing box just to see the preview. If you are interested in better options, which include some kind of preview, you could have a look at posts tagged ([meta-tag:editor]), for example [this one](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4735/mathjax-better-way-to-prepare-a-math-stackexchange-question).)